# Added HTML to iframe causes page to reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got the following HTML code:

```
<iframe id="A1B2C3D4E5" frameborder="no" onload="ajaxStandardCall('/myservlet')" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:solid silver 1px;;"></iframe>
```

In the javascript method, I have;

```
function ajaxStandardCall(urlString){
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'html',
            url: urlString ,
            success: function(msg){
                $("#A1B2C3D4E5").contents().find('html').html(msg);
            },
            failure:  function(msg) {
                $("#A1B2C3D4E5").contents().find('html').html(msg);
            }
     });
}
```

What is does is that it get whatever HTML returned from the servlet and set it as the HTML of the iframe.

However, when I run this, it shows corrected result page but immediately goes to blank page. It looks to me that it make some other requests to refresh the page.

There is no reload method etc in the return HTML. Is there any obvious mistake of the above code that causes this?

Many thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you have a function directly within a function?

Comment: sorry. that was an edit error. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe has to have a closing tag:

```
<iframe id="A1B2C3D4E5" frameborder="no" onload="ajaxStandardCall('/myservlet')" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:solid silver 1px;"></iframe>
```